# Is there a bounded dense subset of norm linear space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

I have a question. In norm linear space $X$, we can find a bounded dense subset of $X$, can´t we?

Comment: Can you do this in $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean norm?

Answer (score 1):

You can only if $X$ is bounded itself. This is because of the continuity of the norm.

Consider a bounded dense part $B$, 2 sequences $x_n,y_n \in B$ such as $x_n\to x, y_n\to y$ and such as, $D$ being the diameter of $X$, $\|x-y\| > D- \epsilon$. Let $D_B$ be the diameter of $B$.

$$
D_B\ge \|x_n-y_n\| \to \|x-y\| > D-\epsilon
$$
using the continuity of the norm,
which implies $D_B \ge D$ (and as $B\subset X$, $D_B = D$).

Hence $D_B < \infty \implies D<\infty$.

---

NB:
continuity of the norm:
$$
f = \|.\|:X\to \Bbb R^+\\
|f(x) - f(y)| \le \|x - y\|
$$is the triangle inequality.

Comment: A normed space is rarely bounded...

Comment: yes, but you can consider a (bounded) part of a norm space with the induced norm topology.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.